# Angular 12: How to replace component template in angular.json

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I used to replace template files by passing configurations earlier like this in angular.json file:

```
"fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "global/components.abc.html",
              "with": "global/components.def.html"
            }
]
```

But now it's giving me errors on build:

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "/fileReplacements/2" must have required property 'src'.
Data path "/fileReplacements/2/replace" must match pattern "\.(([cm]?j|t)sx?|json)$".
Data path "/fileReplacements/2" must match exactly one schema in oneOf.
```

I went through some articles and found out that **this has been the case since Angular CLI version 9. Previously however the offending file replacements were silently ignored.**

A solution however is provided here: [#14599 (comment)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14599#issuecomment-527131237) but it only provides a way to replace index.html files.

My question is there's a correct way to replace component template files? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: why u try to replace whole comp template? maby u do something wrong? u can use env file in comp and define if statement

Comment: in my project we replace base index.html with index.prod.html bec prod have some counters & analitycs only for prod mode. All other comp just use env setting and conditions

Comment: I have multiple projects that run based on the build configs. In this particular instance, I have to maintain 2 instances of the template file as both reference different components that are exported from different projects.

Comment: ok. so u can try use condition in @Component decorator before u set templateUrl. Did u try this?

Comment: u must try to rewrite logic and build apps based on env config. angular.json need for build configuration, but not replace each component (this isn't good)

Comment: Changed the approach to keep the template file within the specific project directory. Saved me a lot of conditions within the template. Thanks :)

Comment: @Abhishek, perhaps you could post an answer with how you managed to replace components' html files at build time?

Answer (score 1):

## Dont use `fileReplacements`

- they do not work for any other assets other than the matching `regex`

### For index.html

As correctly pointed out, `index` is a special case,
and it is handled with the link provided in the question

- It is included in the answer below

---

## Solution for any resource type

##### Use case:

I wanted to replace `.htaccess`, `favicon.ico`, and other resources.
The below approach specializes the `assets` in the build environments you want `production`/`development`.

## Steps:

### 1. Created new folders in `environments`

- not sure if that is the correct location
- but I want everything that relates to different env in that folder

[image]

### 2. Adjusted build targets:

- in `angular.json`

```json
// ...

"production": {
              "index": {
                "input": "src/environments/prod/index.html",
                "output": "index.html"
              },
              "assets": [
                // assets that must be included in all cases (common stuff)
                "src/sitemap.xml",
                "src/robots.txt",
                "src/assets",
                {
                  // mapping the root folder to /, for all files
                  "input": "src/environments/prod/root",
                  "output": "/",
                  "glob": "*"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                // DOES NOT WORK HERE
              ],
              
              // ...
            },

// similarly for development
"development": {
              "index": {
                "input": "src/environments/dev/index.html",
                "output": "index.html"
              },
              "assets": [
                "src/sitemap.xml",
                "src/robots.txt",
                "src/assets",
                {
                  "input": "src/environments/dev/root",
                  "output": "/",
                  "glob": "*"
                }
              ],
              // ...
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the OP's case of replacing a component's html file as stated, does it?  Those aren't assets that sit in the `dist` folder, they are combined with the component's `css` and `ts` files into a `js` file at build time.